# In Elsevier Editorial System, how do I resend a paper with "Submission needing revisions" status?

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission, editors

I've received a letter from the editor about minor revision to my paper and, if I want, that I can resend revised manuscript. The paper is currently under "Submissions needing revision" in Elsevier Editorial System (EES).

Do I need to notify the editor by mail or somehow through EES that I will resend the revised version or just send it again right after making changes/replying to reviewers' comments?

Answer (score 1):

The expected action would be for you to quickly but thoroughly make the necessary revisions to your paper. Sometimes the journal, through the electronic submission system or through the decision mail, provides a time frame for revisions. in my environment minor revisions is commonly expected within 3 weeks and major revisions within 6 weeks of receiving the comments. This is by no means a universal time frame so you should try to figure out what applies in "your" journal.

What is important is that you address each of the comments received and provide a clear account for how you have done so. You should make the revisions as quickly as you can. If you are uncertain about the time frame, send an e-mail to the editor and ask. Since a minor revision is likely to be follow by acceptance if revisions are made successfully, also go through and make sure your manuscript adheres to journal style requirements. This is usually given by an "Instruction for Authors" (or equiv.) but can also be gathered from looking at a recently published paper in the journal. Pay particular attention to the reference system.

Comment: I asked the editor about the time frame because I didn't received any explicit deadline. He said the sooner, the better; the maximum is 6 months.

Comment: Good, then sooner is better. The time frame is clear and the sooner you complete the revisions, thesooner the paper can be published (given that your revisions are deemed sufficient)